# Create a .dll Library consisting GUI Components windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8, sdk, windows-phone

I have to create a library which i would like to reference in other project. However I would like to include in other projects. So basically when there is a button click I have to switch to the application pages created by my library. Is there any way to do this kind of project in windows phone SDK. I am using visual studio 2012 for windows sdk 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create this kind of an library using the standard Windows Phone Class Library -project. You can add pages and classes to this project as if it was a regular Windows Phone Application-project. To navigate to page which resides inside a class library, use the examples provided in here: http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/wp7-navigating-to-a-page-in-different-assembly

**Example:**

We have created a simple class library which contains pages for dealing with PayPal payments. We reuse this component in few of our apps. The library contains few pages:

[image: PaypalPages]

When we want to use that library in our app, we just reference the DLL. After that, we just have to navigate the user to the correct Uri:

```
frame.Navigate(new Uri(string.Format("/Adafy.Payment.Client.WindowsPhone;component/Pages/ProductDescription.xaml?productId={0}", productId), UriKind.Relative));
```